# Samples from a multivariate t distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, mathematica

Hi I have the following problem.
I draw a sample of a multivariate t-distribution with some fixed covariance matrix, 
so that the realizations are correlated, and $\nu=4$. Now I repeat this $n$ times, always with the same covariance matrix and the same $\nu$.
I normalize each sample to mean 0 and standard deviation 1 and look at the histogram of all samples, it is a Gaussian distribution.

I somehow expected a t-distribution with the same degrees of freedom $\nu=4$. Why do I see a Gaussian distribution?

PS: I don't think the code is the problem since I already asked in a forum and it seems correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but when I compare with a Gaussian and a student-t distribution, I can see that the histogram is clearly Gaussian.

Comment: Here is my question, I work with Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81440/random-variables-from-a-multivarite-t-distribution

Comment: And this is the multivariate t distribution which I use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution

Comment: did you try to plot the un-normalised samples?

Comment: yes I did, I normalized because I wanted to compare with the pdf of the normal and the t distribution. What should the histogram of the un-normalized samples tell me? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Posting the same question on several SO sites is a **very** bad practice. It wastes the precious resource of people with expertise, and it confuses the readers / newcomers on the site. Since your question is statistical in nature, I'd say you would want to delete the Mathematica.SE question.

Comment: @StasK: Normalisation is indeed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your normalizing the samples to mean zero and variance one kills all of the heavy tail properties of the $t$-distribution. Since $T_\nu = z/v_\nu, z\sim N(0,1) \perp v_\nu \sim \chi^2_\nu$, your normalization of the scale by 1 annihilates $v_\nu$ forcing it to be one instead of a random quantity. The deviations from zero are due to the $z$, but you force them to have the variance of exactly one. As a matter of fact, I suspect that your normalization produces lower variance than one... probably 299/300 or 298/300, although you are not going to notice it on a histogram.

That the code *runs* (i.e., does not crash and does not produce errors) does not mean it is *correct* in the sense that it solves *your* problem... which you have not stated, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an experiment that exhibits a clear lack of fit by a Gaussian density for a simulated t sample:

```
library(mvtnorm)
x=rmvt(1e4,sigma=matrix(c(1,.7,.7,1),nrow=2),df=4)
hist(x[,1]/sd(x[,1]),nclass=123,col="wheat2",prob=TRUE)
curve(dnorm,add=TRUE,lwd=2,col="sienna2")
```

However, since there are different definitions for the multivariate t, it may also be that you use one for which the marginals are not t's...

[image]

Comment: Ok I am confused now, then I must do something wrong, I work with Mathematica actually. Above I posted the link to my question in a Mathematica forum. I have to check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Because you get multivariate Student t as the fraction of the normal vector and a chi-squared random variable. So, of course, the histogram of entries of the vector will be normal, but for every simulation, it will be different normal, depending on what the chi-squared random variable shows you. If you normalize, chi-squared gets cancelled and it will just be standard normal all the time.